# Обработчик нажатия кнопки с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

У меня есть класс Button:

```
class Button {
        private:
            int RectHeight = 0;
            int RectWidth = 0;
            wchar_t* Text = (wchar_t*)(L"\0");
            struct text_object {
                const wchar_t* text = 0;
                unsigned int text_size = 0;
            };
        public:
            Button(int rect_height, int rect_width, wchar_t* text) {
                Text = text;
            }
            ~Button() {
                Text = 0;
            }
            void DrawButton() {

            }
        };
```

Кнопка ещё не доделана, но сейчас это не важно. Кнопка имеет прямоугольную форму. Приложение использует CreateWindowExW для вызова окна и кнопка будет находится в этом окне. Как правильно проверять, что в области моей кнопки была нажата левая кнопка мыши? Единственное, что мне приходит в голову - это сделать цикл, который будет вечно проверять, находится ли мышь в области моей кнопки и нажата ли при этом левая кнопка мыши. Но есть ли способ получше?

Comment: Для этого в WinAPI существует готовый виджет кнопки, который будет присылать соответствующее событие. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/buttons

Comment: а можно ли как то это сделать без использования стандартных кнопок?

Comment: Можно конечно, нужно будет реализовать все то, что уже реализовано в стандартных кнопках.

Comment: вот я и хотел бы узнать их структуру. Есть ли ресурс, где можно узнать реализацию этих кнопок?

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Например можно заглянуть в код wxwidgets или еще какого проекта GUI.